# Populate a playa hidden input field

Tags: safecracker, playa, channel-form

How must I populate a playa hidden input field (in a safecracker form) with multiple entries? I tried passing the entry IDs separated by comma, semicolon, bar, but nothing seems to work. Only the first entry in the array gets saved. How do I have to format the entry IDs for multiple relationships to be saved?

Update: Thanks to Jeremy I now know how to add data to Playa correctly. Alas, it's still not working, now I get PHP errors.

This is what I have (inside a safecracker form):
    
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel-name" category="{category_id}" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination"}

{title}{if {embed:parent_id} == '{exp:playa:parent_ids}' }
                                        {if:else}
                                        {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}

I make a list with checkboxes. The conditionals check whether this entry is related to the entry currently being edited. So when it's related

```
<input class="relate" type="hidden" name="playa_field[selections][]" value="{entry_id}"/>
```

gets displayed, when it's not related

```
<input class="relate" type="hidden" name="0" value="{entry_id}"/>{/if}</label>
```

gets displayed. This works fine.

In the footer I load jQuery and this code to look for changes on checkboxes. When a checkbox is changed the "name" attribute gets updated.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $checkboxes = jQuery("#tag_list").find(":checkbox");
        $checkboxes.on('change', function () {
            var $relate = jQuery(this).siblings('.relate').attr("name"),
            $name = "playa_field[selections][]";
            if ($relate == $name) {
                jQuery(this).siblings('.relate').attr( "name", "0" );
            }
            if ($relate != $name) {
                jQuery(this).siblings('.relate').attr( "name", "playa_field[selections][]" );
            }
        });
    });
```

This also seems to work, I can see the "name" attribute get changed in the Safari developer tools.

But now, when I submit the field I get a bunch of the following PHP errors:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Filename: playa/ft.playa.php

Line Number: 2356

Severity: Warning

Message: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array

Filename: playa/ft.playa.php

Line Number: 2356
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to actually use multiple hidden fields, each adding to an array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cf_playa_field[selections][]" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="cf_playa_field[selections][]" value="456">
```

You could also potentially write an extension to rework the POST data if you absolutely must submit the values in one field.

Comment: Thank you. Do all of these hidden input fields need to be next to each other? Because I don't have them one after another and am getting PHP errors: "Severity: Warning
Message: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
Filename: playa/ft.playa.php
Line Number: 2356"

Comment: It should work from anywhere in the form. Can you update the post with the relevant portion of your template?

Comment: OK, I added template code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got this squared away. It seems like my name="0" inputs were causing the errors. Now I remove the complete hidden input when a checkbox is unchecked and create a new one on the fly when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: Glad you got it working!